# UTF-8 issue with CoreNLP server

Tags: utf-8, server, stanford-nlp

I run a [Stanford CoreNLP Server](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) with the following command:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

I try to parse the sentence `Who was Darth Vader’s son?`. Note that the apostrophe behind `Vader` is not an ASCII character.

The [online demo](http://corenlp.run/) successfully parse the sentence:

[image: screenshot of the online webserver of CoreNLP]

The server I run on localhost fails:

[image: screenshot of the localhost webserver of CoreNLP]

I also tried to perform the query using Python.

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:9000/'
sentence = 'Who was Darth Vader’s son?'
r=requests.post(url, params={'properties' : '{"annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner", "outputFormat": "json"}'}, data=sentence.encode('utf8'))
tree = r.json()
```

The last command raises an exception:

```
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 1172 (char 1171)
```

However, I noticed occurrences of the character `\x00` in the text (i.e. `r.text`). If I remove them, the json parsing succeeds:

```
import json
tree = json.loads(r.text.replace('\x00', ''))
```

Finally, `r.encoding` is `ISO-8859-1`, even though I did not use the option `-strict` to run the server. Note that it does not change anything if I manually replace it by `UTF-8`.

If I run the same code replacing `url = 'http://localhost:9000/'` by `url = 'http://corenlp.run/'`, then everything succeeds. The call `r.json()` returns a dict, `r.encoding` is indeed `UTF-8`, and no character `\x00` is in the text.

What is wrong with the CoreNLP server I run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with the 3.6.0 release. If you build the server from GitHub, it should work properly with UTF-8 characters. Setting the appropriate Content-Type header in the request will also fix this issue (see https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/125).